# Issue with entering in enable mode in Cisco devices when connected with SSH

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, cisco

I am able to doing ssh to cisco devices and its working fine. I am able to run EXEC mode commands but I am not able to execute privileged commands. It looks like I need to enter into enable mode but I am not sure about the arguments that needs to be passed in ssh. My code is as below. Can you please help me? Thank you for any help.

```
import os 
import getpass 
import paramiko 
import xlsxwriter 
import socket 
import  re 
import sys 
import smtplib 



username = 'username' 
password = 'password' 

print "Running the tests..this might take some time.." 

# Opens file in read mode 
f1 = open('hostfile','r') 
f2 = open('commandfile','r') 
# Creates list based on f1 
devices = f1.readlines() 
commands = f2.readlines() 

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient() 
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy()) 

data = [] 
for device in devices: 
        column = device.split() 
        data.append([column[0]]) 
        print column[0] 
        for command in commands: 
            try: 
                    conn=ssh.connect(column[0], username=username, 
password=password, timeout=4) 
                    if conn is None: 
                        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command) 
                        x=stdout.readlines()
                        print 
'*****************************************************************'
                        print ' Output of ' + command + ' on ' + device
                        print 
'*****************************************************************'
                        raw_input("Press any key to continue.")
                        for j in x:
                            print j
                         data[-1].append(stdout.read()) 
                        ssh.close() 
            except  paramiko.AuthenticationException: 
                    output = "Authentication Failed" 
                    data[-1].append(output) 
                    break 
            except  paramiko.SSHException: 
                    output = "Issues with SSH service" 
                    data[-1].append(output) 
                    break 
            except  socket.error, e: 
                    output = "Connection Error" 
                    data[-1].append(output) 
                    break 
        data[-1] = tuple(data[-1]) 


f1.close() 
f2.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

One way would be to setup the user with higher privileges and eliminate the need of entering into enable mode. If the AAA is setup for local authentication on the Cisco device, adding privilege 15 in the username command will do the trick.